# Matching portion Deletion, and find out some matching keywords from a String

Tags: java

I want to replace a few words from a String,which is present inside a text file. Whenever a match will be founded it will remove that match. Example : “Learning java is not so easy but also /* is not so much hard */  int a, int b, char c ". All that I need to replace the whole comment section and associated words with it( /*----------*/) and print the keywords as many times it will be founded . In this case what I should do ? Here is my code .

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
   {
        File f1=new File("Read_A_File.txt");
        File f2=new File("New_Generated_File.txt");

        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f1);
        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f2);

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);

        String st;
        while((st=br.readLine())!=null) 
        {    
         if(st.contains("/*"))
           {
                bw.write(st.replaceAll("([/*-*/])", " "));  
           }

           System.out.println(st);
           bw.newLine();  
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP6GT.png)

Comment: Post code as text and not as an image and also add an explanation of what i wrong with your code

Comment: I want to explain why this question will likely be closed. StackOverflow's mission is to answer questions like "I did X, expecting the result Y, but instead I got Z, why?", and where the answer will be useful to other people. This question is more like trying to find what approach to use, which doesn't fit well to Q&A format, and it's so specific to the assignment that it won't help other people (unless they got the same assignment).

Answer (score 0):

One of the basics of programming. I find the simpliest is to find the separators, and cut out the parts you want to keep, and concatenate them. For example:

```
String str = "word word, /*comment*/ drow drow";
String result;

int start = str.indexOf("/*");
int end = str.indexOf("*/");

result = str.substring(0, start+1)+str.substring(end, str.length()-1);
```

Or put it into a loop if needed. At first, you search for the indeces of the comment start and end, then just cut out of the needed parts with substring. (According to documentation, start is inclusive and end is exclusive...), also, you have to negate one from length, since it returns the total length, but the indeces start with 0. This approach also pleases the bloodthirsty gods of programming.

An another approach could be a for cycle with deleteCharAt(), where you just go through the string and deleting the characters one by one:

```
for (int i=0; i<end-start; i++) {
 str.deleteCharAt(start);
}
```

It's nice because the basic idea is the same regardless of language. The second one is also a godproof solution.